# Remove rows which have all NAs in certain columns

Tags: r, dataframe, na

Suppose you have a dataframe with 9 columns. You want to remove cases which have all NAs in columns 5:9. It's not at all relevant if there are NAs in columns 1:4.

So far I have found functions that allow you to remove rows that have NAs in *any* of the columns 5:9, but I specifically need to remove only those that have *all* NAs in columns 5:9.

I wrote my own function to do this, but since I have 300k+ rows, it's very slow. I was wondering is there a more efficient way? This is my code:

```
remove.select.na<-function(x, cols){
  nrm<-vector("numeric")
  for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
    if (sum(is.na(x[i,cols]))<length(cols)){
      nrm<-c(nrm,i)
    }
    #Console output to track the progress
    cat('\r',paste0('Checking row ',i,' of ',nrow(x),' (', format(round(i/nrow(x)*100,2), nsmall = 2),'%).'))
    flush.console()
  }
  x<-x[nrm,]
  rm(nrm)
  return(x)
}
```

where x is the dataframe and cols is a vector containing names of the columns that should be checked for NAs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This a one-liner to remove the rows with NA in all columns between 5 and 9. By combining `rowSums()` with `is.na()` it is easy to check whether all entries in these 5 columns are `NA`:

```
x <- x[rowSums(is.na(x[,5:9]))!=5,]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `all` with `apply` to find rows where all values are `NA`:

```
x[!apply(is.na(x[,5:9]), 1, all),]
```

or negate `is.na` and test for `any`:

```
x[apply(!is.na(x[,5:9]), 1, any),]
```

or using `rowSums` like [@RHertel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51600298/10488504) wher you dont need to calculate the number of selected rows:

```
x[rowSums(!is.na(x[,5:9])) > 0,]
```

Answer (score 6):

Here are two `dplyr` options:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(a = c(0, NA, 0, 4, NA, 0, 6), b = c(1, NA, 0, 4, NA, 0, NA), c = c(1, 0, 1, NA, NA, 0, NA))


# columns b and c would be the columns you don't want all NAs

df %>% 
  filter_at(vars(b, c), any_vars(!is.na(.)))

df %>% 
  filter_at(vars(b, c), any_vars(complete.cases(.)))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     1     1
2    NA    NA     6
3     0     6     1
4     4     4    NA
5     0     0     0
```

---

In the newer version of `dplyr`, use `if_any`

```
df %>% 
      filter(if_any(c(b, c), complete.cases))
```

Comment: nice solution! turns out that `any_vars()` is superseded in favor of `across()`. However, I wasn't able to translate the solution here to rely on `across()`. Any hint?

Comment: @M-- Perhaps `df %>% 
  filter(if_any(c(b, c), complete.cases))`

Answer (score 0):

```
lines=
   'V1   V2   V3   V4  
    A    10   20   NA   
    B    NA   NA   NA   
    C     5   20   3     
    D    15   20   4    
    E    NA   10   5'

df = read.table(textConnection(lines), header = T)

df[is.na(df)] = 'X'


attach(df)

x = subset(df, V2 == 'X'   &   V3 == 'X'   &   V4 == 'X')
df_new = df[-as.numeric(row.names(x)),]
df_new

#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  A 10 20  X
#3  C  5 20  3
#4  D 15 20  4
#5  E  X 10  5

detach(df)
```

Comment: But this function will delete cases that have ANY missing values in columns 3 & 4. As outlined above, I need to delete only cases that have ALL missing values in columns 3 & 4. In other words: 

-If there is a missing value in column 3, but not in column 4, the case shouldn't be deleted.

- If there is a missing value in column 4, but not in column 3, the case shouldn't be deleted. 

- Only if there is a missing value BOTH in column 3 and column 4 should the case be deleted. 

- It's not important at all if there are missing values in columns 1 & 2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it's any faster than your function, but maybe you could use `!any` and `is.na` for each row of your data frame. With this example data:

```
set.seed(1234)
x = do.call(cbind, lapply(1:9, function(x) runif(10)))
x[sample(length(x), size = 70)] <- NA
x <- data.frame(x)

> x
     X1 X2   X3   X4   X5   X6   X7   X8  X9
1  0.11 NA   NA 0.46 0.55 0.07   NA   NA  NA
2  0.62 NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 0.04   NA  NA
3    NA NA   NA 0.30   NA   NA   NA 0.01  NA
4  0.62 NA 0.04 0.51   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA
5  0.86 NA   NA 0.18   NA   NA   NA   NA 0.2
6  0.64 NA   NA   NA   NA 0.50   NA 0.52  NA
7    NA NA   NA   NA 0.68   NA   NA   NA  NA
8    NA NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA
9    NA NA   NA   NA   NA 0.17   NA   NA  NA
10   NA NA 0.05   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA
```

Looks like the 4th, 8th, and 10th rows should be dropped. So, you can use `apply` to iterate over each row to see if the condition is satisfied- any row where with any values other than `NA` in the 5th to 9th column will return `TRUE`, so you can use that as an indexer for your data frame.

```
keep.rows <- apply(x[, 5:9], 1, FUN = function(row){
  any(!is.na(row))
})

> x[keep.rows, ]
    X1 X2 X3   X4   X5   X6   X7   X8  X9
1 0.11 NA NA 0.46 0.55 0.07   NA   NA  NA
2 0.62 NA NA   NA   NA   NA 0.04   NA  NA
3   NA NA NA 0.30   NA   NA   NA 0.01  NA
5 0.86 NA NA 0.18   NA   NA   NA   NA 0.2
6 0.64 NA NA   NA   NA 0.50   NA 0.52  NA
7   NA NA NA   NA 0.68   NA   NA   NA  NA
9   NA NA NA   NA   NA 0.17   NA   NA  NA
```

Again, not sure that it's faster than your function but... maybe?