# How to remove rows if a list of columns is completely full of NAs (not removing the rows with at least one value other than NA)

Tags: r

I've got a dataset similar to the one below (but with millions of rows), and I wanted to remove the rows where the columns REVENUE were ALL NAs (in the dataset below, the lines c and e).

[image]

I saw a similar post in the link ([R - Remove rows which have all NAs in certain columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51596658/r-remove-rows-which-have-all-nas-in-certain-columns)) but the answer was using the position of the columns (I would rather use their names) and I didn't understand what they meant by "!=5".

You can get a replicable dataset with the code:

```
dat <-   data.frame(Company = c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), survey_year = c(2014, 2010, 2006, 2014, 2006, 2010), rev_01 = c(NA, 20, NA, NA, NA, 10), 
         rev_02 = c(10, 50, NA, 30, NA, 20), rev_03 = c(20, NA, NA, NA, NA, 30), rev_04 = c(NA, NA, NA, 50, NA, 50), 
         rev_05 = c(NA, 30, NA, NA, NA, 60), variable = c("U", "P", "X", "E", "T","T"))
```

Thank you!

Comment: There are answers in the link you posted that use names too

Comment: `!=5` means not five.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` to find columns with `rev` and use `all` with `apply` to find rows where all are `NA`.

```
dat[!apply(is.na(dat[,grep("^rev", colnames(dat))]), 1, all),]
#  Company survey_year rev_01 rev_02 rev_03 rev_04 rev_05 variable
#1       a        2014     NA     10     20     NA     NA        U
#2       b        2010     20     50     NA     NA     30        P
#4       d        2014     NA     30     NA     50     NA        E
#6       f        2010     10     20     30     50     60        T
```

Or you can use `rowSums` like:

```
dat[rowSums(!is.na(dat[,grep("^rev", colnames(dat))])) > 0,]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is.na()` + `rowSums()` + `subset()` to get the desired output

```
subset(dat,rowSums(is.na(dat[grep("rev",names(dat))]))!=5)
```

such that

```
> subset(dat,rowSums(is.na(dat[grep("rev",names(dat))]))!=5)
  Company survey_year rev_01 rev_02 rev_03 rev_04 rev_05 variable
1       a        2014     NA     10     20     NA     NA        U
2       b        2010     20     50     NA     NA     30        P
4       d        2014     NA     30     NA     50     NA        E
6       f        2010     10     20     30     50     60        T
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be selecting the columns with `dplyr::vars` and `dplyr::starts_with` and remove the rows with `dplyr::filter_at` and `dplyr::any_vars`. This is just a small adjustment of https://stackoverflow.com/a/51600309/10754831

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("rev")), any_vars(!is.na(.)))
```